# Does Amazon S3 guarantee write ordering?

Tags: concurrency, amazon-s3, cloud

Amazon S3 provides an "eventual consistency" model, where data you store is eventually visible to all clients.

I can't find any official information as to whether write ordering is guaranteed or not. This is fundamentally important if you are building an architecture where a client might want to read data right after someone else stored it.

If write ordering is preserved, I can easily check whether the data is complete by having the writer store a guard (say, a special key) and the end of the write operation.

If no write ordering is guaranteed, then I have a serious problem, because there is no way I can be sure I can safely read the data.

I read Werner Vogel's article on consistency (http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2007/12/eventually_consistent.html), where he notes that systems without monotonic write consistency are notoriously hard to program, but does not say whether S3 guarantees it or not.

Comment: Are you planning on overwriting files?

Comment: No, I only write once. But I need to write a number of files and when I tell another piece of software that the data is complete, I need it to be accessible.

Answer (score 3):

It would be very foolish of Amazon to guarantee write ordering when it's goal is massive scalability. Consider the following case:

- A value X associated with key K exists in S3.
- Client 1 (Hong Kong): writes value A to key K, serviced by Server A
- Client 2 (Kansas City): writes value B to key K, serviced by Server B

Eventual consistency guarantees that all readers, any where in the world, will either see value A or value B or value X, and eventually, all readers will see either value A or B, but not a mix.

If Client 1 and 2 issued their writes at the same time then the only way to guarantee write ordering is to associate the writes with each other along a time line. However, transatlantic clocks won't be perfectly synchronized. The real question here is what do you mean by write-ordering, when two clients at opposite ends of the world issue a write close together in time.

**Update**

The same holds true for a single client. Suppose that a value is served from 2 locations, and a single client issues 2 consecutive updates. If both writes are served by the same end-point then it is likely your ordering will be preserved. However, nothing prevents a read from being satisfied from a second location (routing, network split, etc...).

Comment: What I mean by write-ordering is "single-client" write ordering. E.g. when a _single client_ makes a bunch of writes, will all others see the writes in the same order they were made?

Comment: I updated the description:
The same holds true for a single client. Suppose that a value is served from 2 locations, and a single client issues 2 consecutive updates. If both writes are served by the same end-point then it is likely your ordering will be preserved. However, nothing prevents a read from being satisfied from a second location (routing, network split, etc...).

Answer (score 2):

To answer your direct question, 'Does Amazon S3 guarantee write ordering?', I think the answer is no. I'd ask in the AWS forums just to be sure though.

If you can live with near-perfect consistency I'd recommend having your writer check for all the files before returning success. While this doesn't *guarantee* that the file will be available to all clients, it's good enough for most use cases. Personally, I've never had a problem with the consistency of S3 for clients when I've done this. I should note that this will take a bit more time and you'll pay a bit more for the extra requests, but in your case, it's probably worth it.

On the other hand, if you need guaranteed perfect consistency, I'd recommend using a region other than the US Standard region. All regions except for the US Standard region offer ["read-after-write consistency for PUTS of new objects and eventual consistency for overwrite PUTS and DELETES"](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#What_data_consistency_model_does_Amazon_S3_employ). This should solve your problem for new writes, but again, it'll cost a bit more.

Best,

Zach

Developer, LongTail Video