# Expected behavior for file naming of Snowflake S3 Integration?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**goal**: confirm that the file naming behavior in the below picture is expected for the [Snowflake S3 integration](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-config.html) given the code I am using

**code:**

```
copy into s3://bucket-name/ga_sessions_YYYYMMDD from EDW_DEV.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS.GA_TO_S3 file_format = google_analytics_json_format storage_integration = SNOWFLAKE_TO_S3;
```

**expected result is suffix values that ascend in order:**

- ga_sessions.YYYYMMDD_0_0_0
- ga_sessions.YYYYMMDD_0_0_1
- ga_sessions.YYYYMMDD_0_0_2

**what I'm actually getting:**

[image]

Comment: How frequently are you running this  ? I mean within the same day. Read this SO link and see if this is related to your issue . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184886/does-amazon-s3-guarantee-write-ordering let me know.

Comment: I typically see what you are expecting when the data volumes are high enough to warrant it, but not always.  Can you share the size of the warehouse that you are using?  It should be noted that the size of the warehouse dictates how many threads there are to create files, while the amount of data dictates how many threads are actually used.  The numbering shouldn't be considered an order that the data was extracted, as each file is created in parallel by the warehouse.  If you are using a very large warehouse for not much data, then I could see the results you've shared as being valid.